# Проблемы с DTMF в связке Huawei E173 + Asterisk 13 + PJSIP + chan_dongle

Tags: asterisk, операторы, модемы, openwrt, pjsip

**Что имеется**: OpenWRT + Asterisk 13.18 + PJSIP + chan_dongle + Huawei E173 (11.126.15.00.209) и кодеки: ulaw alaw g722 gsm.

На данный момент asterisk сервер стоит на роутере [TL-WR1043NDv4](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/hwdata/tp-link/tp-link_tl-wr1043nd_v4) в имеет только один пир (endpoint) для тестов

**Суть проблемы**: Когда набираю сервисные номера операторов (через sip
клиент) то после прослушивание автоинформатора на определеном этапе "застревает" и не слышно потом ничего но канал не прерывается. Что это может быть и как ее решить? Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все решилось шаманством параметров в `dongle.conf`:

```
mindtmfgap=45 ; minimal interval from end of previews DTMF from begining of next in ms
mindtmfduration=80 ; minimal DTMF tone duration in ms 
mindtmfinterval=200 ; minimal interval between ends of DTMF of same digits in ms
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, не отвечайте фразой «спасибо». Вместо этого, **[отметьте лучший ответ как принятый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)** (галка напротив выбранного ответа). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/229071)

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр Изменил ответ. Спасибо за разъяснения